# How to hide child pages under specific parent from wordpress search result

Tags: php, wordpress, function, search, plugins

I have been looking for a way to tweak my wordpress search results.

**This is what I want:**

In my site I have posts, pages & and custom post types. Now there are certain pages which in a child page of other page. For example, let's say there is a parent page called `Services` and there are 5 child pages under it named as `ABC Service`, `XYZ Service` and so one.

Now I want to return the following things only, in the wordpress search result:

- All Posts
- Pages (Not the Services Page and any child pages under it). So all page will show up in the search except the `Services` page and all the 5 child page which has parent page set up as `Services`.
- Other custom post types

**This is what I did:**

First I created a small function to check the sub pages:

```
function ism_is_subpage() {
    $post = get_post();

    if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) {
        return $post->post_parent;
    } else {
            return false;
    }
}
```

after this I have created a wordpress `pre_get_posts` filter call to pass it though. Like this:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', function( $query ) {
    if (!$query->is_admin && $query->is_search) {
        $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'page', 'other-post-type1'));
    }
    return $query;
});
```

But the problem is no matter how I call the `ism_is_subpage()`, I am not getting my desired result.

Can any of you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the page id you could do something like this:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', function( $query ) {
    if (!$query->is_admin && $query->is_search) {
        $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'page', 'other-post-type1')); //this line to specify post types as it is already in your question
        $query->set('post_parent__not_in', array($post_id));
        $query->set('post__not_in', array($post_id));
    }
    return $query;
});
```

Check [Post and Page parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) and keep in mind that [pre_get_posts hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) is called after the query variable object is created, **but before** the actual query is run.

**EDIT**

First `$query->set(.....)` line as it was in your question does post type filtering, you have to add all post types that you want to search and dont forget [default post types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) like 'nav_menu_item', etc. And yes. You have to put post ID (ID of your parent page) for example 44.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your helpful reply. I have a few questions. First in the post_id above, do you want me to put the parent page's I'd? Also I don't see a way to mention posts, pages, custom post type like I mentioned. Because there are certain custom post type that I don't want to show up in search either.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for the edit. So it seems I don't need the `ism_is_subpage()` anymore. Just just have 1 last doubt. Why you use `post_parent__not_in` & `post__not_in` both? Is it something like `post__not_in` will make sure that the `Services` page itself doesn't show up in the search and the `post_parent__not_in` will make sure that any child of `Services` page will not show up in search. Am I right?

Comment: post_parent__not_in (array) - use post ids. Specify posts whose parent is not in an array. post__not_in (array) - use post ids. Specify post NOT to retrieve.